Mis sesiones ssh se cuelgan y no devuelven el prompt
Tengo un caso con un servidor RHEL 8.9, al ejecutar una conexión ssh desde un segmente de mi VPN (172.29.218.x) directamente, todo marcha bien, me conecto sin problema al servidor y todos los comandos que lanzo, terminan correctamente.
Pero si me conecto desde mi VPN (172.29.218.x) y salto aun nodo  a un nodo 10.201.251.12 y posterior al servidor destino (100.68.23.71), este es el que presenta el problema de que los comandos se cuelgen al ejecutar un #df -hTP  o #ls -l /path o ruta, el prompt se queda colgado y no regresa y no puedo ni terminarlo con un # ctrl + c para cortar el comando.
Pruebas realizadas:

Verifique que el ssh no tenga alguna restricción y tambien probe con la misma configuración de su nodo par y tiene el mismo comportamiento.
A nivel S.O, desabilite SElinux y Firewalld.
Ya cambie de puerto fisico de red del servidor y configuré la red en otro puerto y hace el mismo comportamiento.
No hay FS llenos a nivel del S.O.
No hay ningún NFS o CIFS montado en el S.O.

Desde la ILO del servidor, no tiene ese problema ni con root u otra cuenta distinta.
Alguien ha tenido algo similiar o que pueda orientar a indagar un poco más?
Agradeceria a todos el aporte de cada uno de ustedes.
saludos.

¿Te puedes conectar al 100.68.23.71, te da prompt pero no ejecuta los comandos?

1/ verifica los pasos en https://serverfault.com/a/654232/442275 para ver si necesitas definir rutas en el nodo intermedio 10.xx.yy.zz ( puede que el trafico "de vuelta" esté por fuera del vpn, o no sale/es filtrado en la subred de 10.xx.yy.zz )

2/ con varios saltos entre subredes podes estar teniendo un problema de mtu ( doble o triple nat ) ahi podes probar diferentes metricas de paquetes empezando por el "recomendado" 576, para ipv4  por ej. sudo ip li set mtu 576 dev eth0  reemplazar eth0 por la interfaz correspondiente, mtu 1280 es el min para ipv6

3/ prueba conectado con screen para mantener varias terminales y poder recuperar la que se cae. con screen o directo usando varias sesiones podes monitorear el daemon y las conexiones en el server.
